# Short Sci-Fi story about an astronaut circling a planet where evolution happens very fast

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to identify a Sci-Fi (short I think) story that I read many years ago, probably in the 80's.

The core of the story was that an astronaut is stranded around a planet in a stationary orbit. He manages to make contact with the inhabitants but can only speak with them for a short time before the planet circles round and he loses contact. When the inhabitants come back into range again they have evolved exponentially and this cycle continues for several iterations until they eventually save his life. I can't remember exactly how but I seem to recall that it involves the physical moving of a planet or sun that was what he was at risk from.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in any more details you may remember! Lastly, don't forget to take the [tour]!

Comment: Fast evolution makes me think of "Dragon's Egg", but that's a station of scientists, not one astronaut, and it's a book.

Comment: Sounds like a recent episode of the Orville.

Comment: This sounds like _children of time_ by Adrian Tchaikovsky, but this is a novel and not from the 80's, maybe he got inspiration from the story you are looking for

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have seen this question before. Haven't been able to find it yet though.

Comment: "The planet circles around and he loses contact"? But you said the astronaut is in a "stationary orbit"? Isn't that an orbit where the orbital period matches the rotation period of the planet, so the orbiter remains over the same part of the planet?

Comment: It's also the same idea as was used in an episode of ST Voyager.

Comment: @MrLister - Are you thinking of the question about "Gift of a Useless Man" by Alan Dean Foster (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31020/short-story-from-early-70s-where-the-hero-is-a-bandit)?

Comment: @Otis No, a spaceship around a planet. And ISTR there were more people on the ship than just the one.